# Getting jQuery datepicker live, when html is loaded from ajax

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, datepicker

I have the following jQuery script defined on all my forms.

```
$( "input:text.datepicker" ).datepicker({ 
    yearRange: "1900:+0",
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true
});
```

Basically this invokes the date picker on any input element that is of type text and has the class "datepicker".

This works fine on all pages, except in one situation which I describe below.

I have to load a form by ajax, which is then displayed in a jQueryUI Dialog. In this dialog I can only get the date picker to display **if** I include the java-script code again. Obviously I don't want to include the code twice. Is there a way to get the newly loaded textbox to display the date picker somehow?

Thank you

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One option is to [use `on` method](http://api.jquery.com/on/) in *deprecated* `live` way and [`click` event](http://api.jquery.com/click/) to initialize Datepicker:

```
$('body').on('click', 'input.datepicker', function(event) {
    $(this).datepicker({
        showOn: 'focus',
        yearRange: '1900:+0',
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true
    }).focus();
});
```

This code should be placed in `$(document).ready` section.

Pay attention to `showOn: 'focus'` option and triggering [`focus` event](http://api.jquery.com/focus/) after initialization.

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/Mq93s/

Comment: (1) You only need to call `.datepicker()` once per input, the datepicker is smart enough not to double-bind so this isn't a big deal. (2) This won't work properly if you use the `buttonImage` option.

Comment: @muistooshort Is that a comment for my answer? :)

Comment: Yes, just pointing out a few caveats of the bind-on-click approach.

Answer (score 2):

Well the problem here is that when the datepicker code is executed, your form element does not exist yet, and therefore, it cannot convert it to a datepicker. You could bypass this problem by either:

1. Moving the datepicker code to a separate function that you will then call manually from all pages in the `document.ready` event. This way it will only be declared once, and you can also call it in your ajax page as well, only there you will call it when the ajax call is completed instead of the `ready` event.
2. Since you know what you're loading in your form, you can convert just that given input to a datepicker. This is not such a clean solution, because if you will want to change something in the datepicker, you'll have two places to modify, at least.

Both approaches are valid, the choice is up to you, as you know which version fits your project better :)

Comment: Hi and thanks for the ideas. I have tried option 1, by calling the function after loading the html and it works perfectly. I had actually tried this before, but I called the function before displaying the dialog, and this did not work. Now that I call it after displaying the dialog, it works.